# Array list showing wrong results?

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I am parsing a json array and adding the values to individual array lists.But the size of the array list goes from 1 to 3 and then 6.
This is my code.

```
private ArrayList<String> employee_name = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> emp_username = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> emp_password = new ArrayList<>() ;
private ArrayList<String> employee_role = new ArrayList<>() ;

public void travRoleArray() throws JSONException {
    response = "{\"result\":" + rolejson.toString() + "}";
    Log.d("RESPONSE",response);
    JSONObject jsonOb = new JSONObject(response);
    JSONArray result = jsonOb.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);
    try
    {
        for (int i=0; i< result.length();i++)
        {
             JSONObject jObj = result.getJSONObject(i);
             employee_name.add(i,jObj.getString(KEY_NAME));
             emp_username.add(i, jObj.getString(KEY_UNAME));
             emp_password.add(i, jObj.getString(KEY_PASS));
             employee_role.add(i,jObj.getString(KEY_ROLE));
         }

         for (String name:employee_name)
         {
             Log.i("Name : ",name);

         }
     } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
     {
         Toast.makeText(UserRegistration.this, "Array Index out of bound exception", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }

 }
```

I tried logging the result and the array list contains the 1st item, 2nd item and the 1st item again. E.g.:

> Name :: Anup
>
> Name :: Sakets
>
> Name :: Pritam
>
> Name :: Anup
>
> Name :: Sakets
>
> Name :: Anup.

Any help or suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Clear array before use! in function

Comment: Why do you use ``add(i, someObject);`` and not simply ``add(someObject)``?

Comment: Can you post the raw JSON response?

Comment: Agree with @f1sh, using add(someObject) can avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. I'm thinking the "response" object contains duplicated data. So, as Nadir's comments, should post the response